# PFFacebookUtils logInWithPublishPermissions doesn't load permission screen

Tags: objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, permissions, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm working on a Parse application where i need `publish_actions` permission from user after login. I'm using PFFacebookUtilsV4 framework.  I've tried

```
[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] fromViewController:controller handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (result.isCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"permission denied");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"permission granted");
    }
}];
```

this pop up safari browser but doesn't load anything. am i doing something wrong with above code or what could be the possible issue?

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:nil];
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    }

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

plist

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>XYZ</string>
```

Comment: Can you show me you App Delegate?

Comment: What are the contents of your .plist ?

Comment: Thanks @MilanMendpara I've created an answer

Comment: @Simon .plist values just added in description

Comment: @MilanMendpara The behaviour that you describre is very strange, I'll look for another solution

Comment: @JulienKode your response and suggestions are much appreciated! it makes me believe that i'm very close to source of the issue and atleast its not an issue with the code you've mentioned!

Comment: @MilanMendpara No problem :) So the first time it works and second not ? 

Can you logout and retry I think you are logged and try to relog you

Answer (score 0):

In Swift I have this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "MY_APP_ID"
        $0.server = "MY_SERVER_URL"
    }
    Parse.initialize(with: configuration)

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

You can configure like this:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>YOU_APP_ID</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

To login with permission I used this:

```
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"]) { (user: PFUser?, error: Error?) in
        if error == nil, let ruser = user {
            print("WORKS")
        }
        print("EPIC FAIL")
    }
```

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: @MilanMendpara I have the same in my app, Have you initialize parse before ?

Comment: @MilanMendpara Can you try with : logInInBackground ? please if you configuration and setup is good, It works

Comment: loginInBackground working for the first time as expected with read/write permission. But issue is with second time asking permission.

Comment: second time if i try [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithPublishPermissions] it opens and close safari page immediately

Comment: Can you show me log ? It returns a user the second time or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Simple solution :) Also, User should have tester or admin role to test your app if your app is not approved by Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

- LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
- Facebook App ID and App display name
- Must have app URL type like fb
- Exception domains

  ```
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
      <string>fbauth</string>
      <string>fbauth2</string>
      <string>fbshareextension</string>
  </array>
  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>xxxFACEBOOKIDxxx</string>
  <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
  <string>App Name</string>


  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
      <key>facebook.com</key>
      <dict>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
          <false/>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
      </dict>           
  </dict>


  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
          <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
          <string>Editor</string>
          <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
          <array>
              <string>fbxxxFACEBOOKIDxxx</string> // should have URL types
          </array>
      </dict>
  </array>
  ```